# force private member access from same class only through method in java

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I want to force future users of a class to access a private member also from future code written in that class only through an accessor method (even through junit or anything like that).

is there a way to do it in java? can someone show an example if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot force to do that, but you can create a method and document that enforcement in the javadoc.

```
private int myMember;

/**
* ATTENTION: use this method instead of setting the member directly.
*/
public void setMyMember(int value) {
  this.myMember = value;
}
```

Also, there is an alternative solution which might work. Use ThreadLocal, like this:

```
private final ThreadLocal<String> member = new ThreadLocal<String>();

public void setMember(final String value) {
  member.set(value);
}
```

The member field is final and cannot be changed. Therefore, clients will be forced to call the setter directly.

Comment: This does not create any security! See the other answers.

Comment: The alternative solution does create a security.

Comment: Looks good but we still can call `member.set("12345")` from outside the classes own setter method. It still does not force people to use the getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the field is part of the class, anyone can access it directly. This can be a problem when we try to force all (co-)authors to go through the getters/setters because those method do some conversion, checking or bookkeeping stuff. Like incrementing internal counters.

A general solution, that comes to mind: it could be possible by using annotations. You'd have to create an annotation (and the annotation processor code) to ensure, that it is a compile time error if the field is used outside of it's getter/setter method:

```
@GetterSetterAccessOnly
private int value;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent reflection you can use a SecurityManager.  If this is not an option you can get the call stack with Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() and check the caller is from your class.

Two problems with this are; the performance won't be great.  Anything you can do in the method you can do externally so the simplest work around is to copy its contents without the check. ;)

I suggest you document your reason for not allowing access this way.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of inheritance to hide the field:

- Do your class with all the fields and getter/setters that you need. (You may make it abstract)
- Do a child class, that inherits from the previews one, and since the field isn't accessible, you force the use of the getter/setter pair.

Comment: Thought about that, but the usage is limited: the "child class" will not have access to other private fields in the "parent class". This could be a show stopper.

Comment: Change the ones you want permit access to 'protected'! But is also always a good idea, make use of getter/setters (more setters) since you can do validations and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about the accessing in the same class, they have all the freedom to access the private member directly as well as through accessor method if that member has. **So basically you cannot prevent them using the member directly in the same class.**

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no standard way to do that. If a user has access to a class instance, although a private member is declared private, permissions can be changed at runtime and accessed anyway.

You need a classloader that enforces permissions. You can make an OSGi Bundle and enforce a control policy over the instance of your objects exported as services through interfaces. However this will tie you to an OSGi container to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if they have access to your code, they can do anything they want. In the worst case, they remove your getters and setters and just put in a public field instead ;)

But of course you can motivate them to not access the variable directly with an according design:

- you should check whether the others should rather implement **subclasses** instead of changing the class itself. Then private fields are, of course, only accessed via setters and getters.
- you could **move the data into a different class**, and use your getters and setters to access the data in the other class. Doing this just for the sake of not having the data directly in your class is maybe a bit counter-intuitive, but since you probably have a good reason why they shouldn't access that very data, it indicates a different responsibility. So refactoring to meet the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is a good idea anyways.